# Incompatible type card cannot be converted to string

Tags: java

Not sure how to fix this error, I commented where the error in the code, very new to java. I am trying to send my cards into my constructor and create a deck array.

```
public abstract class CardGame {
    protected String[] deck = new String[52];
    private String[] Suit = {"Spade","Dimond","Heart","Club"};
    private String[] Card = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","jack","queen","king","ace"};

public CardGame(){
    int c = 0;
   for (int x=0; x < Suit.length; ++x){
       for (int i = 0; i < Card.length; ++i){
           deck[c] = new Card(Suit[x], Card[i]); // heres the error
           c++;
       }

    } 

}

}

public class Card {
   String suit;
   String name;

public Card(String s,String n){
    suit = s;
    name = n;
}

public String getsuit(){
   return suit;
}

public String getname(){
   return name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
protected String[] deck = new String[52];
```

You have an array representing your cards as type String, when you probably want to have an array of type Card if you intend to insert cards into that deck.

For your problem line to work:

```
deck[c] = new Card(Suit[x], Card[i]);
```

You'll need to declare deck like so:

```
protected Card[] deck = new Card[52];
```

Comment: TYVM that worked, so im guessing with protected Card[] deck = new Card[52]; i created a card data type array? oop is very confusing.

Comment: @user3538292 Think of your data structure (your array) as a container that only fits a specific type of object, like an egg carton can only contain eggs, or a bowling ball bag can only contain bowling balls. A bowling ball does not belong in, nor would it fit, an egg carton. When you declare a data structure, you also tell the Java compiler what kind of things belong inside it (typical objects of a specific class or objects subclassed from that class). The more you code, the more you'll get used to this idea. Just remember: every thing has a specific place.